# Sort according to given key order

Tags: perl

Given an array that contains order

> my $ord=("USA",'IN',"AUS","NZ","NEP","CHN","ARG","UK");

Also, we are given hash:

```
my %hash = ("IN" => 'val1', "AUS" => 'val2', 
            "USA" => 'val3',   "UK" => 'val4',
             "CHN"=>'val5',"UK"=>'val6',
              "NZ"='val7',"IN"=>'val8',
               "NEP"=>'val9',ARG=>'val10',
                 "IN"=>'val11');
```

We have to sort this hash on the basis of key in the order of $ord.

That is after sorting, the output should be:

```
"USA"=>'val3'
"IN"=>'val1'
"IN"=>'val8'
"IN"=>'val11'
........
.......
"UK"=>'val4'
```

Is there a simple way to do it in perl?  Or, Do I need to  write such a function by myself?

Comment: Please show examples of what you have tried. While i can provide the answer. Its nice to see at least some attempt or try at the problem from the user. Once you provide a code example of what you tried i am more than happy to show a solution and explain the difference.

Comment: Your `%hash` has a couple of syntax errors in it

Comment: As @TomFenech mentioned, your hash assignment is syntactically broke (`"NZ"='val7'`)... beyond the syntax, however, the multiple values for single keys aren't going to be stored correctly.

I'd take a look at http://bioinfo2.ugr.es/documentation/Perl_Cookbook/ch05_08.htm

Comment: Presumably you mean `@ord = (...)` rather than `$ord = (...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hash can't possibly contain two (or three) elements with the same key. Best to create a hash of arrays.

```
my @data = (
   IN  => 'val1',
   AUS => 'val2', 
   USA => 'val3',
   UK  => 'val4',
   CHN => 'val5',
   UK  => 'val6',
   NZ  => 'val7',
   IN  => 'val8',
   NEP => 'val9',
   ARG => 'val10',
   IN  => 'val11',
); 

my @order = qw( USA IN AUS NZ NEP CHN ARG UK );

my %vals_by_country;
while (@data) {
   my $country = shift(@data);
   my $val     = shift(@data);

   push @{ $vals_by_country{$country} }, $val;
}

for my $country (@order) {
   if (my $vals = $vals_by_country{$country}) {
      for my $val (@$vals) {
         print("$country: $val\n");
      }
   }
}
```